# Apache Every subdomain points to same directory

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I have made something wrong while creating some virtual hosts on Apache and now everytime I go to some_random_subdomain.mysite.com, if this subdomain does not exist or if it is not applied properly it redirects to a specific directory (which is assigned to a specific subdomain) and I don't know what do I have to do to stop it. Some help please.

Comment: Most likely you've got a default wildcard host somewhere that's picking up these non-existent hostnames, and that host is doing the redirect.

Comment: where could this wild card be located?

Answer (score 2):

Have you used `*.domain.com` anywhere? For example:

```
<VirtualHost 111.222.33.4>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This would cause the Virtualhost to be used for all subdomains that don't have Virtualhosts.